# Single NFS folder shared across multiple clients

Tags: nfs, nfs4

I'm trying to mount a single NFS folder from server say "/share/folder" to multiple clients up to 32 clients, and the clients tries to access the folder and create files. The problem I'm facing is that when I execute the write command I see only one client is able to access the folder the remaining clients are blocked and not able to proceed to write. So, is whatever I'm trying to do above is correct? Can we write/read files from the same folder on multiple clients? if yes how can I do it prallel?

Comment: Do you try to write the same file or different files to the same folder? Writing the same file in parallel will not work.

Comment: is rpc.lockd running everywhere?

Comment: Thanks for the reply ppl. I was trying to write in different files. And, I dont see rpc.lockd running anywhere.

Comment: Since I'm using SLES I can see "lockd" is already running.